# cardano-cli: Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 11>: does not exist

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I'm at this part of the [docs](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano). The node is running (left terminal in the image below), but now I'm trying to query the blockchain from another terminal and receive the error:

```
cardano-cli: Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 11>: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

[image: my two ubuntu terminals]

I'm running the cardano node on a windows laptop inside an ubuntu terminal that I downloaded from the windows store (as recommended in the cardano docs [here](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node)):

[image: windows store]

I think that maybe the two Ubuntu terminals are completely independent from each other and that's why the right terminal can't find the socket? I tried to install the cardano node on a raspberry Pi 4 also, so that I have a native environment, but the raspberry was just to slow for it...

**EDIT:**
I have set the socket path now like this at the bottom of my ~/.bashrc file:

[image]

then restarted the terminal, but still I receive the same error.

Comment: have you mentioned the socket location when starting the node?

Comment: I have set the same socket path as I used in the `cardano-node run` command:
`export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH="~/cardano-src/cardano-node/db/node.socket"`

My cardano-node run command looks like this:

`cardano-node run --topology ~/cardano-src/cardano-node/config-files/testnet-topology.json --database-path ~/cardano-src/cardano-node/db --socket-path ~/cardano-src/cardano-node/db/node.socket --host-addr 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --config ~/cardano-src/cardano-node/config-files/testnet-config.json`

and the query command: `cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063`

Comment: when I run `echo $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` in my terminal, it gives me the correct path back: `~/cardano-src/cardano-node/db/node.socket`

Comment: But when I run `ls -al $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` I receive the error: `ls: cannot access '~/cardano-src/cardano-node/db/node.socket': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the problem were the quotation marks. In the docs they use quotation marks too:

`export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH="/home/user/cardano/db/node.socket"`

But here the guy didn't use quotation marks: https://forum.cardano.org/t/cardano-cli-network-socket-connect-socket-11-does-not-exist/38987/7

So I tried it without it in my ~/.bashrc file:
[image]

and it worked after re-starting the cardano-node and the second terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution for myself on a Coincashew tutorial.
https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node#2-build-the-node-from-source-code

Basically i executed this:

```
echo export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH="$NODE_HOME/db/socket" >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

That rewired the node path to socket (on the place of node.socket). Don't know what is the real difference but this way worked while the 'node.socket' path don't.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue while trying to get the Plutus PAB to connect to the node. I tried lots of solutions but didn't get it to work until I changed the "testnet/node.sock" in the config (testnet/pab-config.yml). Perhaps it needed to be relative?

**plutus-apps/plutus-pab/test-node/testnet/pab-config.yml**

```
...
nodeServerConfig:
  pscSocketPath: testnet/node.sock
...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are specifying `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` in these formats:

`"$NODE_HOME/db/socket"` you must use double quotes around it

`~/cardano/db/node.socket` you don't need to give double quotes around it