# problem connecting to testnet (1.34.1; testnet is in Vasil)

Tags: cardano-node, vasil-hard-fork

when starting the testnet node using

```bash
cardano-node run +RTS -N -A16m -qg -qb -RTS \
 --topology testnet-topology.json \
 --database-path testnet/node/db \
 --socket-path node/db/socket \
 --config testnet/node/config_files/testnet-config.json
```

the server starts correctly, but fails connecting to the peers (in order to sync)

my `testnet-topology.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "Producers": [
    {
      "addr": "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io",
      "port": 3001,
      "valency": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

which is the [default one](https://hydra.iohk.io/build/13695229/download/1/testnet-topology.json)

the error I receive is the following

```
Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt Exception,
destination [<probably iohk ip but omitting anyway (ipv6)>]:3001
exception: Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 50>: does not exist (Network is unreachable)
```

and after a while

```
Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Application Exception: <some ipv4>:3001
MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: 
resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"
```

so I assume the problem is in the topology.

is the topology wrong? if yes can you provide the right one?
is the node version a problem due to Vasil?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK 1.35.X is needed for Vasil.

Please check the url below for details:

https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2022/07/04/cardano-s-approaching-vasil-upgrade-what-to-expect/

Edit: Just for clarification, Becky from IOG posted on Discord today
"Please note that we are deprecating node versions 1.35.0 and 1.35.1 . These contain known issues and should not be used. SPOs wishing to test Vasil functions ON THE TESTNET ONLY should do so using node version 1.35.2. SPOs should continue to run 1.34.x on mainnet until an official mainnet release is confirmed."

Cheers,
Josep

Answer (score 1):

You *must* be running `node@1.35.3` to correctly interact with the post Vasil HF chain.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems more at the socket level, as said here:

```
exception: Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 50>: does not exist (Network is unreachable)
```

problem could be related to [question 3734](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/cardano-cli-network-socket-connect-socket-11-does-not-exist)

Do you have the an env variable in your .bashrc file like the following?

```
CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH="/home/user/cardano/db/node.socket"
```

Comment: yes the ```CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH``` environment variable is setted correctly

Comment: Is the file readable by the user that run the cardano-node service?

Also did you check with other relays if you have the same error?